# "MailboxNotHostedInExchangeOnline" when trying to get user photos from MS Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Using

```
`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/${email}/photo/$value`
```

had been working for me last week but now it throws a 400 error
[Error Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0x0pB.png)

"Mailbox is hosted by an on-premise or non-Exchange server, which is not supported."

As far as I know nothing has changed from our end. Using the v1.0 doesn't seem to make any difference. I think the user photos are stored on an on-premise exchange but are then synced up at AAD. This has been working fine for at least a year like this.

Anybody know if anything has changed in the last few days? Any documented solutions to this?

Comment: We've started having users get this error when logging in to an application via OAuth 2.0 to Azure AD, it used to work fine at the start of April. I opened a ticket with Microsoft but it got routed to an Exchange support agent, in the meantime I migrated the affected users to Exchange Online and it stared working for them.

Comment: @TRS-80 could you tell how did you migrate the users to Exchange Online? I'm having the same issue. Some of the users have this problem and some not

Comment: @takeit Just using the normal Exchange Hybrid migration process.

Comment: It's started happening to my user, time to open a case with Microsoft again and hope I get routed to the Azure support queue and not Exchange this time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exchange Online team was trying to clean up some error codes and such they changed `MailboxNotEnabledForRestAPI` with HttpStatus code `404` to `MailboxNotHostedInExchangeOnline` with HttpStauts code `400`. This was un-intended and such we have since reverted this change, and are rolling out the fixes to prod with urgency.

Comment: Hey Yogesh, does this mean that all cases where we've seen `MailboxNotHostedInExchangeOnline` they are still errors? Or are there cases where this error code be thrown where the API was actually successful?

Comment: Thanks for that Yogesh. Does that means that people's photos will start appearing again where they did before?

Comment: This appears to be fixed now in our tenant.

Comment: Fixed for us too.