# MailboxNotHostedInExchangeOnline error during calendar access

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'm seeing this exception `MailboxNotHostedInExchangeOnline` from an MIT (educational institution) Outlook account that we're trying to connect to in order ho to access their calendar events (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars API), but there's not much additional information online about what this exactly means

````
  "error": {
    "code": "MailboxNotHostedInExchangeOnline",
    "message": "Mailbox is hosted by an on-premises or non-Exchange server, which is not supported.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "REDACTED",
      "date": ""
    }
  }
}```

Is this a relatively new addition to the API? If so, does anyone have ideas on how to circumvent this?
````

Comment: it has been fixed by MS team, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61616761/1316350

Comment: Was this previously working?